# "Initialization-on-demand holder idiom" - Lazy loading?

Tags: java, singleton

This [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization-on-demand_holder_idiom) page explains that "Initialization-on-demand holder idiom" uses lazy loading.

**Initialization-on-demand holder idiom**

```
public class Something {
    private Something() {}

    private static class LazyHolder {
        private static final Something INSTANCE = new Something();
    }

    public static Something getInstance() {
        return LazyHolder.INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

**Singleton**

```
public class Something {
        private Something() {}

        private static final Something INSTANCE = new Something();

        public static Something getInstance() {
            return INSTANCE;
        }
    }
```

My understanding is that class `Something` is loaded and initialized when it is called first time.

But again, `LazyHolder` will be loaded at the same time when `Something` is loaded.

Then, how are these two different in terms of initialization? Why is it said that *Initialization-on-demand holder idiom* uses lazy initializtion when compared to usual *Singleton* method?

Comment: `LazyHolder` will be loaded when needed, which is only in `getInstance()`. So you could provide more static methods inside `Something` without loading `LazyHolder` and its initialization. The other Singleton also uses lazy-loading. But creates an instance as soon as `Something` is needed. Meaning additional static methods would also invoke the initialization. I'm not sure if there are more reasons, but this is my 2 cents.

Comment: So that means, its only usage is when `Something` has more static methods. In this case, it is just same.